# Emulator for Android 4.4 KitKat with GPU enabled is not starting

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat

If I create Emulator without GPU enabled, it starts without problems.

*But when I set GPU enabled, it crashes after some time of start* -

[image]

*These are my emulator settings that doesn't work -*

[image]

I also read- [Emulator for Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html), there is a caution -

> Caution: As of SDK Tools Revision 17, the graphics acceleration
>   feature for the emulator is experimental; be alert for
>   incompatibilities and errors when using this feature.

And the compatibility issues -

> To use the graphics acceleration feature, you must have the following
>   versions of the Android development tools installed:
>
> - Android SDK Tools, Revision 17 or higher
> - Android SDK Platform API 15, Revision 3 or higher

*I have the following installed on my system* -

> - Android SDK Tools, Revision 19
> - Android SDK Platform API 19, Revision 3

Comment: may i know the cause of enabling GPU?

Comment: I enable GPU for - 1. To get the significant speed-up. 2. I am using bitmap with canvas drawing feature so this will give boost at graphics stuff. 3. For some reason, emulator is not showing canvas drawing on bitmaps in emulator. SO I want to test with GPU enabled to true if that work.

Comment: why dont you try bluestack or genymotion, bulestack is most good vertual device with latest version availbale

Comment: There are significant problems trying bluestack and genymotion. I tried `genymotion` for 2 days without success. It seems as if it doesn't work with Android 4.4 or higher with Google API's feature enabled. I tried `bluestack` for quite a long time but it doesn't load on my small RAM on system drive. It needs at least 2 GB space which is more for now as I have less storage. Somehow, I have less time and need quick result. So now trying GPU.

Comment: ok , is sdk tool rev 19 installed?

Comment: yes I have it installed on my system.